# Does Right continuity at each point implies continuous a.e?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose f is a function from non negative real numbers to extended non negative real numbers which is right continuous at each point,does it imply that f is continuous almost everywhere in its domain?

Comment: Yes. According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/587764/248286), right continuity implies continuity on the complement of a countable set.

Comment: For a much stronger result proved by William H. Young in 1907-1908, see my answer to [A search for theorems which appear to have very few, if any hypotheses](https://mathoverflow.net/a/231462/15780). [Note that right continuity at $x=c$ is equivalent to $\liminf\limits_{x \rightarrow c^{+}}f(x) = f(c) = \limsup\limits_{x \rightarrow c^{+}}f(x).$]

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is actually stronger.

> Let $f [0, +\infty) \rightarrow [0, +\infty]$ be a right continuous function. Then the set of points where $f$ is discontinuous is a countable set.

**Proof**:

Let $f [0, +\infty) \rightarrow [0, +\infty]$ be a right continuous function. For all $n \in \Bbb N$, $n\geqslant 1$,  let

$$ \Gamma_n = \left \{ I \subseteq  (0, +\infty) : I \textrm{ is an open interval and, for all } x,y \in I, |f(y)-f(x)|< 1/n    \right \} $$

Let $A_n = \bigcup_{I \in \Gamma_n} I$. We have that $A_n$ is an open set.

Let $F_n = A_n^c$. $F_n$ is closed. Now, given any $x \in  F_n$, since $f$ is right continuous, it is easy to see that there is $\delta_x>0$, such that $(x, x+\delta_x) \subseteq A_n$. It means, $(x, x+\delta_x) \cap F_n =\emptyset$. It follows that $F_n$ is countable (see Remark).

Now, $A= \bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}A_n$ is the set of points where $f$ is continuous and we have that $A^c= \bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}F_n$ is countable.

**Remark**: If $F_n$ is uncountable, then there is $k \in \Bbb N$ such that $F_n \cap [0, k)$ is uncountable, but this is not possible, since for each $x \in  F_n$, there is  $\delta_x>0$ such that $(x, x+\delta_x) \cap F_n =\emptyset$.

As pointed out by @EvangelopoulosF. another way to prove that $F_n$ is countable is, for each $x \in F_n$, to pick a $q_x \in \Bbb Q \cap (x, x+\delta_x)$. It is easy to see that the map $F_n \rightarrow  \Bbb Q$ defined by $x \mapsto q_x$ is injective.

Comment: For the countability of $F_n$, for all $x \in F_n$ you can pick a rational number $q_x \in (x,x+δ_x)$. Then the map $F_n \to \mathbb Q $ via $x\mapsto q_x$ is injective

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. Yes, it is another nice way to show $F_n$ is countable. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help